# Jersey Consumes XML post

Tags: xml, post, jersey

I want to make a Post to Jersey Rest service. What is the standard way of doing this?

```
@Post
@Consumes(MediaType.Application_xml)
public Response method(??){}
```

Comment: Hmm. Do you want to make a client POST to an existing service or implement a Jersey RESTful service?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have a java bean say an employee bean such as. Add the tags to tell

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    String employeeName;

    @XmlElement
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
}
```

@XmlRootElement tells that this will be the main tag in xml. In this case you can specify a name for the main tag as well.

@XmlElement tells that this would be the sub tag inside the root  tag

Say, the sample xml that will come as a part of body in the post request will look something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employee>
 <employeeName>Jack</employeeName>
</Employee>
```

When writing a webservice to acccept such an xml we can write the following method.

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getEmployee(Employee employee) {
     employee.setEmployeeName(employee.getEmployeeName() + " Welcome");
     return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(employee).build();
}
```

On calling this service, you will get the following xml as part of the response.

```
<Employee>
<employeeName> Jack Welcome </employeeName>
</Employee>
```

using @Xml...annotations, it becomes very easy to unmarshal and marshal the request and response objects.

Similar approach can be taken for JSON input as well as JSON output by just using the MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON instead of APPLICATION_XML

So for an xml as input, you can get an xml as an output as part of the http response.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example of a post operation:

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Response create(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Customer entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.flush();

    UriBuilder uriBuilder = uriBuiler.path(String.valueOf(entity.getId()));
    return Response.created(uriBuilder.build()).build();
}
```