# Passing Object Using POST

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty

I am trying to pass a parameter in REST however it throws below exception :

```
Mar 15, 2015 3:09:00 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.backend.service.impl.resource.DummyParam, and Java type class com.backend.service.impl.resource.DummyParam, and MIME media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded was not found. The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are: application/x-www-form-urlencoded ->   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormMultivaluedMapProvider
```

The Code snippet is as below:

```
   @Path("/test/dummy")
public class DummyService {

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/doStuff1")
    public Response doStuff1(DummyParam param) {
        System.out.println("Hiiiiiiiiii : "+param.getUsername());
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
@XmlRootElement(name = "dummyparam")
public class DummyParam {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @XmlElement(name = "user")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "pwd")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }



}
```

Can Someone help me what could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to provide a custom MessageBodyReader for your DummyParam class to make it possible to be passed in your request handler.
Take a look at the example here https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you please tell me why its not working by default?

Comment: I think it is because by default jersey does not know what your DummyParam is, and how to read it from request body

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does that mean I need to add a custom MessageBodyReader  for all the param classes I would use in the REST service?Is there any default way to do that?

Comment: Can you also try to use @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML}) I think it may be enough to solve this problem

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203989/jersey-consumes-xml-post